# How can I flag the earliest of overlapping records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a dataset where I need to pick out and keep records that have no overlapping time frames, and for those that do overlap, keep the earliest record.

I have been able to successfully picked out the records that have no overlapping time frames with the below code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#overlaps') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #overlaps
SELECT 
     CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #service r2 
                     WHERE r2.client_ID = r1.client_ID
                       AND r2.service_ID <> r1.service_ID
                       AND r1.service_start_date <= r2.service_end_date
                       AND r2.service_start_date <= r1.service_end_date) 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
   END AS Overlap
   ,*
  into #overlaps
  FROM #services r1
```

This produces the below for an example client:

```
Overlap client_ID   service_ID service_start_date service_end_date   
1        12345       123         27-Oct-2009         03-Jan-2013    
1        12345       124         27-Dec-2012         19-Mar-2013    
1        12345       125         18-Mar-2013         04-Jun-2014    
1        12345       126         29-Jun-2014         28-Apr-2017    
1        12345       127         23-Jun-2014         14-Aug-2014    
1        12345       128         27-Apr-2015         07-Nov-2015    
1        12345       129         01-Aug-2015         01-Dec-2015    
0        12345       132         01-Jul-2017         09-Dec-2017    
0        12345       133         02-Jan-2018         20-Jan-2018    
0        12345       134         03-May-2018         05-Jun-2018
```

What I want to do, is for where overlap = 1, add a column to flag if that record is the first record of an overlapping "set", first in terms of the start date. The service_ID is not actually sequential, I just replaced it to be as dummy data.

So in the above case, record #1 should be flagged a 1 because it has the earliest start of the service compared to its overlapped service record #2 which started later, so record #2 would be flagged a 0, the same for record #3 (ie. flagged as a 0). Going on, record #4 should be flagged as a 1, as it overlaps the ones records below it.

In terms of the final product, I eventually want to just show any non-overlapping periods, and the earliest/first record for the records that do overlap So in the above scenario, records #1,4, 8,9,10 would remain and the rest would be removed. Each record should remain it's own record though, they should not be "pivoted" up into a continuous record.

In other words, what I need to flag are the earliest record that started where there is more than one active service occurring in parallel.

EDIT:

So for example, client has 4 services: Service A started Jan 1 - July 31, Service B Started Feb 1 ended August 1, Service C started September 1 ended Oct 1, Service D started Nov 1 ended Dec 1...Service A should be flagged as 1, Service B which started while Service A was still active should be flagged 0, Service C started without any service being active will be flagged as 1, same as Service D

Comment: I would update `#overlaps` based on a `group by` query from `#overlaps` getting the min(service_id) where overlap=1.

Comment: First in what order? by service id? start date? end date?

Comment: Do you actually want all these flags or do you just want a dataset of contiguous service periods?  It seems like you are asking for assistance on a step in your process, when asking for assistance on the whole thing would yield a more elegant solution

Comment: Can you clarify this statement? "So in the above case, record #1 should be flagged a 1 because it has the earliest start of the service compared to its overlapped service record #2 which started later, so record #2 would be flagged a 0, the same for record #3 (ie. flagged as a 0). " My question is this: Record 1 and Record 2 do overlap, Record 2 and Record 3 do overlap, but Record 1 and Record 3 don't overlap, so should Record 3 be considered part of the overlapping set of Records 1,2,3 or not? If Record 1 is the 1st record in the sequence, then should Record 3 be the first in a new sequence?

Comment: Hello! My original interpretation was, like you said record 3 (service date start March 18)  does overlap with record #2 (service end date march 19). I would think this means record #3 belongs within the Record 1,2,3 sequence. So technically it is record 4 (start date June 29 2014) that would start the new sequence, with record 5, 6 and 7 all falling into that "first" sequence. But the more I think about it your question the more I feel like I will need to ask the end business what to do. If record #3 was considered first in a new sequence though, record #4 would still be a new sequence after.

Answer (score 0):

I think the flag would be:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM #service r2 
                              WHERE r2.client_ID = r1.client_ID AND
                                    r2.service_ID <> r1.service_ID AND
                                    r1.service_start_date <= r2.service_end_date AND
                                    r2.service_start_date < r1.service_end_date
                             ) 
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END) AS First_Overlap;
```

Notes:

- This doesn't actually check for an overlap.  I left that out, because you can use the `overlaps` flag for the check, or include the `exists` query.
- The only difference is `<` versus `<=` for the overlap check on the start date.
- This might not work as you want when the period of overlap has multiple records beginning at the same time.

Also, I suspect you are trying to solve a gaps-and-islands problem.  Using multiple temporary tables and the logic that you are using is unnecessary.  You might want to ask another question about the entire problem you want to solve, rather than this one facet.

Comment: Thanks I will look up to see what a gaps-and-islands problem is. The flag for 0,1 is just to group so whether it is a not exists or exists I think the end result would be the same? Yes, my intent was to have this temp table, then figure out a solution for these "overlapped" records where overlapped = 1, then union the results back to my first table where overlapped = 0 to create my final data set

Comment: @marshymell0  You should definitely just ask a question with your raw dataset and desired output.  You are vastly over complicating this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE #overlaps SET IsFirst=1
FROM
(SELECT overlap, client_id client_id, service_start_date service_start_date, service_end_date service_end_date, min(service_id) service_id
 FROM #overlaps
 WHERE overlap=1
 group by overlap, client_id, service_start_date, service_end_date) a
 where #overlaps.client_id = a.client_id and #overlaps.service_id = a.service_id
```

## Edit

@marshymell0 - I think I'm understanding what you want. Writing this as a query is pretty tricky, so I'm using a cursor instead. In the section where I have the line `PRINT @service_start_date_prev`, is where you would update the flag column that determines if the record is the first in the overlapping set.

```
DECLARE @overlap_prev int, @client_id_prev int, @service_id_prev int
DECLARE @overlap_next int, @client_id_next int, @service_id_next int
DECLARE @service_start_date_prev datetime, @service_end_date_prev datetime
DECLARE @service_start_date_next datetime, @service_end_date_next datetime
DECLARE @part_of_set int = 0
DECLARE o_cursor CURSOR  
FOR SELECT overlap, client_id, service_id, service_start_date, service_end_date 
FROM #overlaps where overlap=1
ORDER BY service_start_date
OPEN o_cursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM o_cursor
INTO @overlap_next, @client_id_next, @service_id_next, @service_start_date_next, @service_end_date_next  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    IF (@service_start_date_prev IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        IF (@part_of_set = 0 AND @service_start_date_prev <= @service_end_date_next AND @service_start_date_next <= @service_end_date_prev)
        BEGIN
            PRINT @service_start_date_prev
            SET @part_of_set = 1
        END
        ELSE
            SET @part_of_set = 0
    END

    SET @overlap_prev = @overlap_next
    SET @client_id_prev = @client_id_next
    SET @service_id_prev = @service_id_next
    SET @service_start_date_prev = @service_start_date_next
    SET @service_end_date_prev = @service_end_date_next

    FETCH NEXT FROM o_cursor
    INTO @overlap_next, @client_id_next, @service_id_next, @service_start_date_next, @service_end_date_next  
END

CLOSE o_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE o_cursor;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but not exactly what I am trying to find. Even if I switch it to find the minimum/earliest start date, it will only find the earliest of all the overlapsI am trying to flag the first/earliest service record that started among the other records that were active at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to read your exact goal here, but if you're looking to flag based on the `service_start_date`, when `Overlap` = 1. This would suffice.

```
;WITH CTE (Overlap, client_ID, service_ID, service_start_date) AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            ('1','12345','123','10/27/2009'), 
            ('1','12345','124','12/27/2012'), 
            ('1','12345','125','3/18/2013'), 
            ('1','12345','126','6/29/2014'), 
            ('1','12345','127','6/23/2014'), 
            ('1','12345','128','4/27/2015'), 
            ('1','12345','129','8/1/2015'), 
            ('0','12345','132','7/1/2017'), 
            ('0','12345','133','1/2/2018'), 
            ('0','12345','134','5/3/2018')
    ) AS A (Overlap, client_ID, service_ID, service_start_date)
)

SELECT CTE.Overlap,
    CTE.client_ID,
    CTE.service_ID,
    CTE.service_start_date,
    t2.Result
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT '1' AS Result,
        t2.client_ID,
        MIN(t2.service_start_date) AS service_start_date
    FROM CTE t2
    WHERE t2.Overlap = '1'
    GROUP BY client_ID
    ) t2 ON CTE.client_ID = t2.client_ID
    AND CTE.service_start_date = t2.service_start_date
ORDER BY service_ID
```

This also does not account for anything other than flagging the first `Overlap` by `service_start_date`. For instance, if you wanted to flag those that aren't first as 0's, that would need to be added.

Comment: Hi, thanks. The main issue is I am not just comparing the start date though, otherwise I would do something like a rank/row_number over (partition by client_ID order by service_start_date).

Comment: What is meant by first then, the smallest `service_ID`?

Comment: First is the start date. So for example, client has 4 services: Service A started Jan 1 - July 14, Service B Started Feb 1 ended August 1, Service C started September 1 ended Oct 1, Service D started Nov 1 ended Dec 1...Service A should be flagged as 1, Service B which started while Service A was still active should be flagged 0, Service C started without any service being active will be flagged as 1, as is Service D